# when i try to run my webpack-dev-server, it gives me following error, that module is not found

Tags: webpack-dev-server

[![const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
mode: "development",
entry: "./src/app.js",
output: {
path: path.resolve(__dirname, "assets", "scripts"),
filename: "app.js",
publicPath: "./src",
},
devServer: {
hot: true,
host: "0.0.0.0",
port: 4000,
open: true,
},
module: {
rules: [{
test: /.css$/,
use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
}, ],
},
plugins: [
new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
//..
}),
],
};][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jV5iQ.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jV5iQ.png)

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6DFP.png]

Comment: Can you please format your code and add information on what you already tried? Maybe copying the Error Message as text into the description would be helpful as well.

Comment: thanks buddy but i figure out my problem..

Answer (score -1):

i have change my command "webpack-dev-server" to "webpack serve" in my package.json file and my code is now working..